# Why is angular making my inputfield empty?

Tags: angularjs, laravel, input-field

The value of my inputfield is set but why is my inputfield still empty ? I am using a combination of laravel en angular :

inputfield html :

```
<input 
        type="text" 
        name="name"
        value="{{ old('name') }}" 
        ng-model="name"
        ng-model-options='{ debounce: 300 }'
        class="form-control"
        ng-class="{ enabled : nameIsValid }"
        ng-change="checkName(name)"
        placeholder="Your nickname"
        required>
```

Comment: Because the property `name` of your scope is probably empty.

Comment: How can i set this property equal to the value of the inputfield?

Comment: ng-model="{{name}}" use braes

Comment: Simply use ng-model and set the property name in angular controller. Remove value attribute no need to put this if you are working with angular ng-model.

Comment: @JimPeeters here is plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/czPOaE9rgt9KGFddZMue?p=preview to give you idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to tell the reason if you don't put your controller code in here. But here are some assuptions from my part:

1. you don't need to set the value if you bind an input-field with ng-model.
2. rather then ng-change I would use a `$scope.$watch()` function
3. are you using more than one `scope` in this template? maybe changes made by the child-scope aren't altering the original variable of the `$parent`-scope